# Access and add the object{} in {array[]} which is the property of an another array[] in Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to add the value (an object{}) in the array[] which is the part or property of the object in an another array in Reactjs using functional components and using hooks!
here part of example code:

```
const  arrayState = {
    array: [
        { id: 1, name: "", Insidarray: []},
        { id: 1, name: "", Insidarray: []}
    ]
}
```

I want to add the values (object like `{name: "", anotherarray: []}`) in the array named `Insidarray` shown above in Reactjs using useReducer, useContext, useState hooks.

Comment: If this array is supposed to be part of the state and you're using hooks, you need `const [arrayState, setArrayState] = useState({ ... });`. Then you update the array by calling `setArrayState` with a suitable new object.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Push a new value to nested array in React hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57571525/push-a-new-value-to-nested-array-in-react-hooks)